# Update Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, query-help

I am a beginner SQL user (not formally trained; OJT only) and need some assistance with a simple update statement.  I would like to write an update statement that allows me to list ID's.  The statement shown below is how I am currently writing it.  Ideally, the statement would allow me to write it like "where plantunitid in (49-57).  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks for any assistance provided.

update plantfunctiontable
set decommissioned=1
where plantunitid in (49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can this work?

```
update plantfunctiontable set decommissioned=1 where plantunitid  between 49 and 57
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Where plantunitid >= 49 AND plantunitid <= 57
```

OR

```
Where plantunitid BETWEEN 49 and 57
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work as is.

Or you can do it like this.

```
Update planfunctiontable set decommissioned = 1 where plantunitid between 49 and 57
```

assuming that your range will always be sequential (1,2,3....7,8,9)

Answer (score 1):

Only if it's sequential, can you use that.

```
UPDATE plantfunctiontable
   SET decommissioned = 1
 WHERE plantunitid BETWEEN 49 AND 57
```

If not sequential, your original query works fine

```
UPDATE plantfunctiontable
   SET decommissioned = 1
 WHERE plantunitid IN (49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Update plantfunctiontable
SET decommissioned = 1
WHERE plantunitid >= @startID
AND plantunitid <= @endID
```

where @startID and @endID are your statements parameters. hope that helps